# Using CAFilter for suckeffect on iOS View

Tags: ios, catransition

I have been reading about creating suckeffect and have found articles that ask to use CAFilter for having an App Store approved suckeffect animation. My doubts are.

1. is CAFilter publicly available or will Apple reject applications using it?
2. Can someone share sample code if they found using this successful in creating such an animation?
3. In which library can i find the CAFilter files

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There will be chance for rejecting your app. This is found in quartz library